# JS / Jquery - Focusing to the next input field from the event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focus, jquery-events

Trying to have it so when a link is clicked aside one input, it will hide that link and focus to the input field in the next div.  I need to reference it with an event-target for other reasons.

If I change `.focus();` to `.val('blah');` it works, and other, more typical methods i.e. `$('a').click(function() {...` will do the job.  Is this just a limitation of using event-target?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/jDXDx/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mousedown event does'nt trigger the handler, you'll need to use click() instead.

Something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jDXDx/3/)

Comment: Nice. My nasty hack was going to be to place a `timeout` before calling the `.focus()` :-)